# Pandas Join DataTable to SQL Table to Prevent Memory Errors

Tags: python, sql, pandas

So I have about 4-5 million rows of data per table. I have about 10-15 of these tables. I created a table that will join 30,000 rows to some of these million rows based on some ID and snapshot date.

Is there a way to write my existing data table to a SQL query where it will filter the results down for me so that I do not have to load the entire tables into memory?

At the moment I've been loading each table in one at a time, and then releasing the memory. However, it still takes up 100% memory on my computer.

```
    for table in tablesToJoin:
        if df is not None:
            print("DF LENGTH", len(df))

        query = """SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT * FROM """ + table + """ (nolock) where snapshotdate = '"""+ date +"""'"""
        query += """ SET NOCOUNT OFF;"""

        start = time.time()
        loadedDf = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
        if df is None:
            df = loadedDf
        else:
            loadedDf.info(verbose=True, null_counts=True)
            df.info(verbose=True, null_counts=True)
            df = df.merge(loadedDf, how='left', on=["MemberID", "SnapshotDate"])
            #df = df.fillna(0)
            print("DATA AFTER ALL MERGING", len(df))
        print("Length of data loaded:", len(loadedDf))
        print("Time to load data from sql", (time.time() - start))
```

Answer (score 1):

I once faced the same problem as you are. My solution was to filter as much as possible in the SQL layer. Since I don't have your code and your DB, what I write below is untested code and very possibly contain bugs. You will have to correct them as needed.

The idea is to read as little as possible from the DB. pandas is not designed to analyze frames of millions of rows (at least on a typical computer). To do that, pass the filter criteria from `df` to your DB call:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, and_, or_

engine = ... # construct your SQL Alchemy engine. May correspond to your `conn` object
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine, only=tablesToJoin)


for table in tablesToJoin:
    t = meta[table]
    # Building the WHERE clause. This is equivalent to:
    #     WHERE     ((MemberID = <MemberID 1>) AND (SnapshotDate = date))
    #            OR ((MemberID = <MemberID 2>) AND (SnapshotDate = date))
    #            OR ((MemberID = <MemberID 3>) AND (SnapshotDate = date))
    cond = _or(**[and_(t.c['MemberID'] == member_id, t.c['SnapshotDate'] == date) for member_id in df['MemberID'] ])

    # Be frugal here: only get the columns that you need, or you will blow your memory
    # If you specify None, it's equivalent to a `SELECT *`
    statement = t.select(None).where(cond)

    # Note that it's `read_sql`, not `read_sql_query` here
    loadedDf = pd.read_sql(statement, engine)

    # loadedDf should be much smaller now since you have already filtered it at the DB level
    # Now do your joins...
```