# Joining in-memory dataframe with very large persisted table in a db?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, dask

I've a dataframe in-memory which has certain identifiers, using those identifiers i want to fetch only relevant data from a very large(500M rows) table persisted in a RDBMS(Sql server).

What's the best way to do this? Definitely don't want to bring the entire table in-memory. And can't loop through either. If it was single column key to lookup, I could still think of building a comma-separated string and doing IN clause against that list but I've multiple fields that are identifiers.

Only option I see is saving dataframe into db, doing join on db server and bringing in data back. But seems so clunky.

I've read about dask as an option, but not really sure about that one because bringing  entire table in-memory/disk still doesnt seem like an efficient technique to me

Comment: Can you try creating Stored Procedure with table valued parameter?

Comment: @RaviDesai: and how do you send a python dataframe into that table valued parameter?

Comment: Don't build the CSV string: you are openning yourself to SQL injection attack. Use SQL Alchemy's `and_` and `or_` functions to filter your table during the query so as few rows as possible are returned to Python. You can take some ideas from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980666/pandas-join-datatable-to-sql-table-to-prevent-memory-errors/60982699#60982699. Edit your question with more details so I can write you a more targeted answer

Answer (score 1):

> Only option I see is saving dataframe into db, doing join on db server and bringing in data back. But seems so clunky.

This sounds like the most efficient option in terms of compute time.

> I've read about dask as an option, but not really sure about that one because bringing entire table in-memory/disk still doesnt seem like an efficient technique to me

If your dataframe with the entries that you care about is small then Dask Dataframe probably won't read everything into memory at once.  It will likely scan through your database intelligently in small space.  The real cost of using Dask here is that you need to move data in and out of the database, which will be slow or fast depending on your database connector.

I would try it out, and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1):

For now I've used a stored proc with table valued parameter(tvp), nice thing is table valued parameter definition can also define indexes on fields.
Pyodbc had implemented tvp in 2018, so all you've to do is create a list of lists as a parameter that matches the datatypes of your user defined table parameter in SQL Server. (Thanks to [RaviDesai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4983953/ravi-desai) for mentioning table valued parameter in the comments)

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

conn_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=test;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password'
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)        
tvp = []
dt = datetime(2011, 3, 4)
tvp.append(['123', dt])
tvp.append(['222', dt])
tvp.append(['333', dt])
sql = "exec dbo.p_test_tvp_sp ?"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=[tvp])
```